# Cannot connect to memcache (Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: /localhost:11211)

Tags: java, web-applications, memcached, connection-timeout, spymemcached

We have hosted a web application using memcache.
Everything has been working fine for the past few years.

All of a sudden I am facing the following error in the application logs, This causes application slowness.

**net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: /localhost:11211**

Also I am unable view the existing memcache configuration using stats command

Can anyone help me on this please.

FYI,
We are using the following version
**memcached-win64-1.4.4-14**

Thanks for the help in advance.